# Can you help me identify this board?

Tags: board

I have found this board installed and I am unsure what it is or what its function is.  I have googled it to no avail.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Please [edit] and post a high resolution, in-focus, cropped photo. A photo of the back might be useful.

Comment: you found it installed, but you won't say where? .... it was installed just like that? ... no cover of any kind?

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  It was installed as is on top of the sky light.  I suspect its a PIR sensor which is meant to switch on and off the down light.

Answer (score 0):

The device in the centre looks like a PIR (passive infrared) sensor. This was recently discussed in [Can we use pir sensor while it's moving?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487419/can-we-use-pir-sensor-while-its-moving/487445#487445).

[image]

*Figure 1. Modified sensing diagram. A pair of side-by-side PIR sensors in reverse-series connection sense motion while giving high immunity to changes background radiation due to temperature changes. Image source: [MakerGuides article](https://www.makerguides.com/hc-sr501-arduino-tutorial/) and modified by me.*

A pair of reverse-series connection that walking into the purple detection zone would generate a positive going pulse and walking into the orange zone would give a negative going pulse.

The photo quality is not good enough to determine anything else.